# SeleniumWebdriver +TestNG: Erratic behaviour in testNg execution of multiple classes done in parallel

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

SetUp & Description:

1. there are 2 test Classes: 1. HomepageTest & SignIntest
2. Methods under these test classes have Groups and Priorities
   **Target is to run these test using groups
   Scebario1: When I use Threadcount =1;

below are the behaviours:

1.1. On execution it launches Homepage > executes Priority 1 of Homepagetest > Then launches

> Then executes priority1 of SignIntest
>
> > After this it executes priority2 of HomepageTest and the priority2 of SigninTest and so on..

1.2. Once Execution finishes, it closes 1 browser (Homepage)but fails to close another browser(SigninPage)

Scenario2: When I use threadcount = 2:

Behaviours:
2.1. It opens 2 Browsers simultaneously In one browser it launches URL(For URL wait for 10 seconds) but in another browser it doesnt launch any URL (Remains blank throughout test process)

2.2: Execution takes place just like 1.1 mentioned above
After execution of few tests then another 3rd broser launches..this 3rd browser closes once exections

finishes but remaining 2 browsers(BlankBrowser and Brwser With URL) remains in open state

2.3 After execution finishes it closes 1 browser but fails to close the browser on which no URL is launched

Quetion1: Why Execution is not on the basis of Group. It is running on the basis of priority as mentioned in 1.1 which looks incorrect.

Ideally it should execute Group1&2 of testClass1 
then it should close that browser Then launch 2nd browser and run Group1&2 tests and then close that browser

Question2: Why It fails to close the 1 Browser. I counted the active window using window handle and count was returning 1 whereas it should be 2

Question3: When thread-count =2 then why it is launching a blank browser(As mentioned in 2.1)

Comment: Please edit your question and help add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample that can be used to reproduce the problem along with all the version details of selenium etc., included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erratic behaviour in testNg execution of multiple classes done in parallel: SeleniumWebdriver +TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131821/erratic-behaviour-in-testng-execution-of-multiple-classes-done-in-parallel-sele)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing groups and priority, and you try to use the incorrect tool to achieve something. And you have extra code that maybe works in one threaded environment, but it can't work in parallel environment, because parallel environment is asynchronous by nature.

Answer 1:

- Groups: Provide only grouping of test methods (by function, or similarity, or by feature).
- Priority: Simply a priority, its a type of ordering. TestNG sees the priority and automatically sorts the tests by it, because you have 2 tests with top priority, it runs them first.
- Grouping is used to manage multiple test case execution, but by group, let's say you need only feature A tests to run, and they all belong to group A, so you run group A.
- There is no ordering implemented on group level, because it doesn't make sense. Grouping is grouping, not ordering. (Example: You see bunch of dogs, and you see it as a group of dogs, not some kind of order like dog A, dog B, dog C etc.)
- Note: If you have some kind of dependency between tests in same class, running TestNG in parallel will run the groups in parallel, because it can't run the tests in parallel caused by their dependencies.

Answer 2:

- If the browser stays open, it's because your code doesn't close it. Maybe you should check how many times you open a new instance, and how many times you close it.
- I suspect by your first scenario that you are opening more than one instance of the browser, but you are using the same WebDriver to manage it, not closing the second instance created.
- WebDriver doesn't just pop up a new browser instance by itself. You need to create an instance to use it. Similarly, WebDriver doesn't just close a browser instance by itself, you need to close it with your code.

Answer 3:

- Look in answer 2.

For future reference: There is no such thing erratic behavior of TestNG or SeleniumWebDriver or event the combination of the two. This is the most common combination of testing tools used by all QA engineers. My company has parallel tests with thread count = 16 and they all work fine.

Keep in mind, test code should be optimized for parallelism, you can't just run regular old tests that were designed for synchronous environment.